# Does Blender have something like a 'prefab'?

Tags: workflow

I'm looking for something like a "**prefab**" in Blender.

I need to create many copies of an object and I want to be able to change the object in the future. I want to change the original object only and have the copies updated.

By changing I mean not just vertices but replace the whole object (sphere -> another form).

**Is it possible to do in Blender?**

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Depending on your intentions, you may consider [Linked Duplicates](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/duplication.html#linked-duplicates) or [Collection Instances](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/instancing/collection.html). Both have their pros and cons.

Comment: Additionally [Library Overrides](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/linked_libraries/library_overrides.html) could be relevant if the objects are stored in separate files.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look

Answer (score 1):

Reading about Library Overrides I found Proxies. It solves my problem perfectly!

[image]

Comment: Link to your reading?

Comment: From official documentation: "Proxies were the historical way in Blender to allow some local editing of linked data-blocks. This was mostly aimed at character animation.

They are now fully deprecated as of Blender 3.0, replaced by the new [Library Overrides](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/linked_libraries/library_overrides.html)."